# Ignite Client crashes JVM while Connecting to cluster

Tags: java, spring, jvm, ignite

I recently changed from running Ignite with Multicast IP Finder to using Static IP Finder to make district sets of clusters per machine.

Prior to this change I was able to establish a connection between the client and the Ignite server.
However, after specifying the Static IP finder in the configuration of the server and the client, when I attempt to connect to the server a IgniteCheckedException: No session found is thrown and takes down the JVM killing my application.  The Ignite server however stays up.

Just to test I tried to revert to the Multicast IP finder but I am now getting the same error.

I have been able to connect to Ignite other clusters, but not the one local to the client.

This is the client configuration:

```
synchronized (igniteLock){
            if(ignite == null) {
                System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
                IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
                cfg.setClassLoader(WSUtil.class.getClassLoader());
                cfg.setClientMode(true);
                cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
                TcpDiscoverySpi spi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
                TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder(); 
                ipFinder.setAddresses(Collections.singletonList("127.0.0.1:47500..47509"));             
                spi.setIpFinder(ipFinder);
                cfg.setDiscoverySpi(spi);
                //start client node 
                ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
            }
        }
        return ignite;
```

Server Configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default is false. -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>

        <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED"/>

                <!--Cache events-->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ"/>
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED"/>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!--
                        Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can be used
                        instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options refer
                        to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config
                    -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of initial nodes. -->
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                   <!-- <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">-->
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Stack Trace:

```
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.662 INFO [tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#38] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Router node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612906587620, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=false]
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.706 INFO [tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#38] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Baseline parameter 'baselineAutoAdjustEnabled' was changed from 'null' to 'true'
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.706 INFO [tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#38] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Baseline parameter 'baselineAutoAdjustTimeout' was changed from 'null' to '0'
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.707 INFO [tcp-client-disco-msg-worker-#4-#38] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info ecstatic_joliot
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.729 INFO [disco-notifier-worker-#35] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Received activate cluster request with BaselineTopology[id=0] initiator node ID: 6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.731 WARNING [disco-notifier-worker-#35] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.warning Received state finish message with unexpected ID: ChangeGlobalStateFinishMessage [id=f0469b88771-c387fe20-8d02-4561-8ee2-86f770e695e4, reqId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, state=ACTIVE, transitionRes=true]
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.734 INFO [disco-notifier-worker-#35] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Assigned mvcc coordinator [crd=MvccCoordinator [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], nodeId=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, ver=1612905390901, local=false, initialized=false]]
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.768 INFO [sys-#39] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Writing cluster ID and tag to metastorage on ready for write ClusterIdAndTag [id=8b0f74e4-d7c6-4ffc-9a59-f809c67418d0, tag=ecstatic_joliot]
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.865 INFO [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], crd=false, evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true, exchangeFreeSwitch=false]
09-Feb-2021 21:36:27.866 INFO [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Components activation performed in 0 ms.
09-Feb-2021 21:36:28.064 INFO [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Started cache [name=ignite-sys-cache, id=-2100569601, dataRegionName=sysMemPlc, mode=REPLICATED, atomicity=TRANSACTIONAL, backups=2147483647, mvcc=false]
09-Feb-2021 21:36:28.065 INFO [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Starting caches on local join performed in 200 ms.
09-Feb-2021 21:36:28.084 SEVERE [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], ...
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No session found
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3986)
                ...
org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3163)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
09-Feb-2021 21:36:29.101 SEVERE [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612906587620, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1612906587747, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.30.138.64:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1612906587500, loc=true, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=true], topVer=4, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@5d71e04d, nodeId8=6c5c16a1, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1612906587720], nodeId=6c5c16a1, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1612906587160, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]]]]
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No session found
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3986)
                ...
09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.121 SEVERE [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Failed to send message to remote node [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612906587620, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=false], msg=GridIoMessage [plc=2, topic=TOPIC_CACHE, topicOrd=8, ordered=false, timeout=0, skipOnTimeout=false, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1612906587747, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], ....
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No session found
                ...
09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.124 SEVERE [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Failed to reinitialize local partitions (rebalancing will be stopped): GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], 
.....
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, ......
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2111)
                ...
09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.125 INFO [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], resVer=null, err=class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612906587620, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=false], topic=TOPIC_CACHE, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1612906587747, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.30.138.64:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1612906587500, loc=true, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=true], topVer=4, msgTemplate=null, span=org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@5d71e04d, nodeId8=6c5c16a1, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1612906587720], nodeId=6c5c16a1, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1612906587160, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]], policy=2], rebalanced=false, wasRebalanced=false]
09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.137 SEVERE [Thread-38] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Got exception while starting (will rollback startup routine).
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, ....
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2111)
                ...
09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.138 INFO [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.info Completed partition exchange [localNode=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, ...
        class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612906587620, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=false], topic=TOPIC_CACHE, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1612906587747, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], ....
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2111)
                ...
09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.144 SEVERE [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], ....
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2111)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.sendToGridTopic(GridIoManager.java:2195)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:1257)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.sendLocalPartitions(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:2138)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.clientOnlyExchange(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:1498)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.preloader.GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.init(GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture.java:952)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body0(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3314)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCachePartitionExchangeManager$ExchangeWorker.body(GridCachePartitionExchangeManager.java:3163)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
        Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to send message to remote node: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612906587620, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=false]
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3050)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:2960)
                at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.send(GridIoManager.java:2100)
                ... 9 more
        Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No session found
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3986)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createTcpClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3635)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createCommunicationClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3375)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.reserveClient(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3180)
                at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.sendMessage0(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3013)
                ... 11 more
09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.150 WARNING [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.warning Page locks dump:


09-Feb-2021 21:36:30.151 SEVERE [exchange-worker-#41] org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger.error JVM will be halted immediately due to the failure: [failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_TERMINATION, err=class o.a.i.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to send message (node may have left the grid or TCP connection cannot be established due to firewall issues) [node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, consistentId=10.30.138.64,127.0.0.1:47500, addrs=ArrayList [10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/127.0.0.1:47500, /10.30.138.64:47500], discPort=47500, order=1, intOrder=1, lastExchangeTime=1612906587620, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=false], topic=TOPIC_CACHE, msg=GridDhtPartitionsSingleMessage [parts=null, partCntrs=null, partsSizes=null, partHistCntrs=null, err=null, client=true, exchangeStartTime=1612906587747, finishMsg=null, super=GridDhtPartitionsAbstractMessage [exchId=GridDhtPartitionExchangeId [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], discoEvt=DiscoveryEvent [evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.30.138.64:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=0, lastExchangeTime=1612906587500, loc=true, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=true], topVer=4, msgTemplate=null, span=o.a.i.i.processors.tracing.NoopSpan@5d71e04d, nodeId8=6c5c16a1, msg=null, type=NODE_JOINED, tstamp=1612906587720], nodeId=6c5c16a1, evt=NODE_JOINED], lastVer=GridCacheVersion [topVer=0, order=1612906587160, nodeOrder=0], super=GridCacheMessage [msgId=1, depInfo=null, lastAffChangedTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=-1, minorTopVer=0], err=null, skipPrepare=false]]], policy=2]]]
```

Ignite Server Output

```
[21:36:27,528][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3-#43][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery accepted incoming connection [rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1, rmtPort=58994]
[21:36:27,528][INFO][tcp-disco-srvr-[:47500]-#3-#43][TcpDiscoverySpi] TCP discovery spawning a new thread for connection [rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1, rmtPort=58994]
[21:36:27,528][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-[]-#6-#191][TcpDiscoverySpi] Started serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:58994, rmtPort=58994]
[21:36:27,532][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-[6c5c16a1 127.0.0.1:58994 client]-#6-#191][TcpDiscoverySpi] Initialized connection with remote client node [nodeId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:58994]
[21:36:27,604][INFO][disco-event-worker-#44][GridDiscoveryManager] Added new node to topology: TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.30.138.64:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1612906587560, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=true]
[21:36:27,604][INFO][disco-event-worker-#44][GridDiscoveryManager] Topology snapshot [ver=4, locNode=9038a060, servers=1, clients=1, state=ACTIVE, CPUs=4, offheap=1.6GB, heap=3.0GB]
[21:36:27,605][INFO][disco-event-worker-#44][GridDiscoveryManager]   ^-- Baseline [id=0, size=1, online=1, offline=0]
[21:36:27,607][INFO][exchange-worker-#46][time] Started exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], crd=true, evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, customEvt=null, allowMerge=true, exchangeFreeSwitch=false]
[21:36:27,608][INFO][exchange-worker-#46][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Finish exchange future [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], err=null, rebalanced=true, wasRebalanced=true]
[21:36:27,609][INFO][exchange-worker-#46][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Completed partition exchange [localNode=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, exchange=GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, consistentId=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, addrs=ArrayList [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, 10.30.138.64, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:0, /127.0.0.1:0, /10.30.138.64:0], discPort=0, order=4, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1612906587560, loc=false, ver=2.9.1#20201203-sha1:adcce517, isClient=true], rebalanced=true, done=true, newCrdFut=null], topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0]]
[21:36:27,609][INFO][exchange-worker-#46][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Exchange timings [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], stage="Waiting in exchange queue" (1 ms), stage="Exchange parameters initialization" (0 ms), stage="Determine exchange type" (1 ms), stage="Exchange done" (0 ms), stage="Total time" (2 ms)]
[21:36:27,609][INFO][exchange-worker-#46][GridDhtPartitionsExchangeFuture] Exchange longest local stages [startVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], resVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0]]
[21:36:27,610][INFO][exchange-worker-#46][time] Finished exchange init [topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], crd=true]
[21:36:27,610][INFO][exchange-worker-#46][GridCachePartitionExchangeManager] Skipping rebalancing (no affinity changes) [top=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=4, minorTopVer=0], evt=NODE_JOINED, evtNode=6c5c16a1-9fcb-41b0-a7d8-1c7081a90e4c, client=false]
[21:36:28,090][INFO][disco-pool-#195][TcpDiscoverySpi] Pinging node: 9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f
[21:36:28,090][INFO][disco-pool-#195][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished node ping [nodeId=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, res=true, time=10ms]
[21:36:29,103][INFO][disco-pool-#195][TcpDiscoverySpi] Pinging node: 9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f
[21:36:29,103][INFO][disco-pool-#195][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished node ping [nodeId=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, res=true, time=3ms]
[21:36:30,123][INFO][disco-pool-#195][TcpDiscoverySpi] Pinging node: 9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f
[21:36:30,123][INFO][disco-pool-#195][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished node ping [nodeId=9038a060-14a3-416f-93b8-e3605a17ca2f, res=true, time=3ms]
[21:36:30,774][INFO][tcp-disco-sock-reader-[6c5c16a1 127.0.0.1:58994 client]-#6-#191][TcpDiscoverySpi] Finished serving remote node connection [rmtAddr=/127.0.0.1:58994, rmtPort=58994
[21:36:31,721][INFO][grid-timeout-worker-#22][IgniteKernal]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are using the java.net.preferIPv4Stack property on the server side as well.

Check your firewall config, to make sure that all listed ports are open.

The issue is w/the communication SPI which, by default is using 47100 and up port range
see: https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/network-configuration#communication

```
    Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: No session found
            at org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi.createNioSession(TcpCommunicationSpi.java:3986)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked as soon as I set the local port to 47500. My only additional question is why did this issue only emerge after I switched to that Static IP finder?